# loop through array of arrays that contains non-reference elements

Tags: arrays, perl

How can I loop through an array of arrays like the following which has elements that are not references?  I get the error: "Can't use string ("10") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use" but if i take out the elements '10' and '11' it prints fine.

```
my @array = (
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    10,
    11
);

foreach my $x (@array) {
   for my $i (0..@$x) {
      if (! @$x[$i] eq '') {
          print "@$x[$i]\n";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Kudos to you for using [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY script.  Glad it was able to help you find this error and therefore know to ask for help.

Comment: Is "AoA" supposed to be "array of arrays"? I've never heard that term before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for my $x (@array) {
   # plain scalar, print it and skip to next element
   if (!ref($x)) { print "$x\n"; next; }

   for my $i (@$x) {
      print "$i\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about 'ref'.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
for my $i (0..@$x) {
```

is where your problem currently lies. For each value in `@array` it attempts to place it in Array context via the `@` sigil. If your element is not a reference to an Array, this will throw the error you are seeing.

What you *can* do is check if you are looking at an arrayref or a scalar before your inner loop begins:

```
ITER:
foreach my $x (@array) {
   if (not ref($x)) {
      print "$x\n";
      next ITER;
   }

   for my $i (0..@$x) {
      if (! @$x[$i] eq '') {
         print "@$x[$i]\n";
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use he [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) function to decide how to print an element of your array. It returns `ARRAY` if its parameter is an array reference, or the null string if it is a simple string or numeric value.

This program demonstrates

```
my @array = (
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    10,
    11
);

for my $item (@array) {
  if (ref $item) {
    print "@$item\n";
  }
  else {
    print "$item\n";
  }
}
```

**output**

```
1 2 3 4 5
x y z
10
11
```

The body of the loop can be made much more concise using the conditional operator. This code is equivalent

```
print ref($_) ? "@$_\n" : "$_\n" for @array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is convert anything that's a scalar into an array reference.  This avoids code duplication (and the risk of error that that entails).

For example, take your array:

```
my @array = (
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    10,
    11
);
```

One could use a temporary variable to either hold the original value (`$row`) if it is already an array reference or create an array reference to hold the original value (if it's a scalar).  From then on you can use the cooked value in place of the original.  For example:

```
foreach my $row (@array) {
    my $cooked = ref $row eq 'ARRAY' ? $row : [ $row ];
    print "@$cooked\n";
}
```

This outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5
x y z
10
11
```

One can also eliminate the temporary variable:

```
foreach my $row (@array) {
    foreach my $item ( @{ ref $row eq 'ARRAY' ? $row : [ $row ] } ) {
        print "$item\n"
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

This directly evaluates the coercion code as an array (with `@{` ... `}`) and iterates over it.  The output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5

x
y
z

10

11
```

Similar code can be used, e.g., for hash references (`ref $variable eq 'HASH'`)